# Terminal Counting it self

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,m;
    int count = 0;
    scanf("%d" "%d", &n, &m);
    
    for(n=m;n>0;n=n/10);
    
    printf("%d\n",count++);
    
    return 0;
}
```

How can I do this with this main code or I just need something edit? I struggled how to can it be count like this sample:

Sample Input 1 (standard input)

```
1 5
```

Sample Output 1 (standard output)

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: So the problem is take two numbers as input and print from _num1_ to _num2_?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You did not tell us what you want to do. A terminal does not count. It is used to do input and output for you. You will have to count if you need counting.

Comment: You should generally turn up warning level in your compiler. For GCC use `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`. It should tell you that `for(n=m;n>0;n=n/10);` looks fishy as it only contains an empty instruction (`;`) in the loop body.

Comment: What is the use of entering a value for n if it is to assign it another one afterwards.

Comment: I see a division by 10 (which won't work, by the way, you will end up with zero). Why are you doing that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you want a simple counter that counts from one number to some other large number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int lowerbound, upperbound;

  scanf("%d %d", &lowerbound, &upperbound);  // string simplyfied
    
  int counter;
  for (counter = lowerbound; counter <= upperbound; counter++)
  {
    printf("%d\n",counter);
  }
    
  return 0;
}
```

That's the classic introductory sample of the `for` loop that you can find in about every beginner's C text book.

Note the new selfdescribing variable names which makes your code easier to read and to understand.